# Getting Data From Backbone Collection Fetch()

Tags: object, collections, backbone.js

I'm relatively new to Backbone, and I'm trying to pass data back and forth between my server-side code. I have a collection setup:

```
var AppCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: AppModel,

    url: 'data.php'

});
```

And then in my view I have my initialize pulling:

```
initialize: function(){
    items = this.collection.fetch();
    console.log(items);
}
```

Which outputs the `items` object. I've tried `console.log(items.responseText)` to just print out the contents of the returned JSON but I'm getting `undefined`.

Here's what I'm seeing in my console with `console.log(items)`:

[image]

My goal is just to output that responseText. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) says `.fetch()` returns a `jQxhr` object.

There are two possible ways to achieve, either you can write success and error callbacks to the fetch like this:

```
this.collection.fetch({
  success : function(collection, response) {
    // code here
  },

  error : function(collection, response) {
    // code here
  }
});
```

Or you can bind an event to reset method of the collection which is fired after the collection is successfully loaded.

```
this.collection.bind("reset", method_name);
```

You can access the collection on the `method_name`, as it will be executed after the `fecth()` ajax is executed. But I would suggest to use the first way as the second has its own other use cases.

Comment: How to access this jQxhr object in a seperate file?